# Column 'book-category' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm facing a problem in this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM `book` join `journal`  
 WHERE  `book-category` LIKE '$maincat2' 
   AND `book-category` LIKE '$subcat2'  
   AND `book-category` LIKE '$country2' 
   AND `book-category` LIKE '$procat2'
```

the table strukture are same book=journal

What is the reason?

Comment: It is ambiguous because both table contains `book-category`. You need to supply tell mysql what table will the column will be searched. eg `WHERE book.\`book-category\`...` or `WHERE journal.\`book-category\`...`

Comment: Of course, once you get this one right, you'll hit another issue, namely the "How can a column match 4 mutually exclusive patterns simultaneously?" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's me but your query as it is doesn't make much sense to me.

Probably you wanted something like this (using `UNION` instead of `JOIN`) and if, as you said, table schemas actually are the same for `book` and `journal`

```
SELECT 'book' type, b.* 
  FROM book b
 WHERE book-category LIKE '$maincat2' 
   AND book-category LIKE '$subcat2'  
   AND book-category LIKE '$country2' 
   AND book-category LIKE '$procat2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'journal', j.* 
  FROM journal j
 WHERE book-category LIKE '$maincat2' 
   AND book-category LIKE '$subcat2'  
   AND book-category LIKE '$country2' 
   AND book-category LIKE '$procat2'
```

Answer (score 1):

both `book` and `journal` have a `book-category` column, so MySQL doesn't know which one to apply the condition on. You can solve this by fully referencing them with a table name.
E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM `book` join `journal`  
 WHERE  `book`.`book-category` LIKE '$maincat2' 
   AND  `book`.`book-category` LIKE '$subcat2'  
   AND  `book`.`book-category` LIKE '$country2' 
   AND  `book`.`book-category` LIKE '$procat2'
```